# How to show next 7 days while using datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

```
function getNext7WorkingDays(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();
    if(day>=0 && day<=3) return 9;
    else if(day!=6) return 10;
    else return 11;
}
$('.datepicker_quiz_dataa').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d-m-Y',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate: 1,
    maxDate: '+'+getNext7WorkingDays()+'D'
});
```

In this code I using datetimepicker where I am getting only date in `d-m-y` format and I want that it show current date to next 7 days dates only but now I am getting previous 14 days dates. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="datepicker"></div>
 
<script>
$( "#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: 6,
  dateFormat: "d-m-y",
  onSelect : function(r) { console.log(r) }
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using datetimepicker @NafisIslam

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
$('.datepicker_quiz_dataa').datepicker({ 
       minDate: 0,
       maxDate: "7d",
       dateFormat: "d-m-y"
});
```

OR

```
$('.datepicker_quiz_dataa').datepicker({ 
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "1w",
      dateFormat: "d-m-y"
});
```